# JUnit tests pass when I run mvn tests by packages, but when I run all the packages together some of the tests fail

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I wrote some integration tests with Kafka. I flagged them with @DirtiesContext but when I run all the tests together, some of them fail cause the kafka messages end up going across the tests as they are running in parallel and then they fail.

Is there any way to run each test in a complete separate context or maybe just run them sequentially one by one?

I'm trying to run: mvn test

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely run each test class in separate jvm, for gradle it's  forkEach property of test task, maven should have something similar. But you can also have test listener that consumes/clear all messages from Kafka between tests invocations.
Another solution is to spin separate instance of Kafka per test using docker, see`test containers`project.